# protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute - port over to .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have been porting over **.net code to .net core** and there are some areas that are challenging.
One such area is in a MVC base controller override method

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    OpsManager.ActiveApplicationId = ApplicationId;
    return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
}
```

> I gather than a lot of the old System.Web.MVC is deprecated.   How can I "fix" or replace this method?

Comment: You *don't* need such an override even in "classic" ASP.NET MVC. If you check the default ASP.NET MVC template with Application Insights support you'll see that application IDs and other logging metadata are added through filters and extensions, *not* through a hard-coded base controller

Comment: What is OpsManager? I suspect the *real* question should be "How do I use OpsManager in ASP.NET Core?" or "how do I inject environment metadata" ? Again, check how the default template handles Application Insights

Comment: Good comments.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method on the `Controller` class:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    // Do something...
    await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to apply some logic to *all* requests (not just for a single controller) you might want to look into [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware).

Comment: Working for me:-)